# Rails 4 - Stripe subscriptions and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to combine stripe subscriptions with the devise gem for user authentication.  All the tutorials I see out there are either dated or don't combine the two. In Views/Devise/Registrations/new

is that where I put the hidden field for the stripe_card_token?

Thanks

Comment: As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a whole lot out there because they don't really need to be combined. It depends on what you want the flow to be really.

For example, I didn't want a user created until after a successful payment so I generated the Devise controllers (tells you how on the github site for the gem) so I could override the registration to add the stripe payment code before "super" and if it failed the account didn't get created. If you do it this way, you put the custom form with the hidden field in the Views/Devise/Registrations/new.html.erb view. You can put the custom form right below the password confirmation code but before the submit button.

However, another way is to add payment after a new user is created with Devise. In the Devise controller for Registrations there is a commented out blurb at the bottom that you can use to redirect a user after they create an account. You can point this to anything. I decided to do this instead and just redirect them to a new subscription view after they created an account just incase they change their mind before payment and come back later (they won't have to re-enter details). I created a whole new scaffold for subscriptions to do this.

The last option is much easier. If you want a kind of wizard for signup, you can use the Wicked gem.